Is there an automatic way to cut geometry up evenly in Blender?
I'm creating a simple 3D level for a Unity game. I'm planning on using trimsheets to texture this level with low resolution, seamless textures. I used Probuilder in Unity to box out the level's geometry, and I've imported this draft as an OBJ into Blender. I'm trying to finalize the geometry in Blender but I've noticed it's a bit painstaking to create evenly-divided geometry out of quads. I'm attempting to do this so that each surface can use the trimsheet and the texture will be evenly spread across the geometry.
Is there a way in blender to just model with non-uniform quads, and then let the material handle applying the texture in a grid-like manner?
Here's a picture of what I'm currently doing (painful)

Here's a picture of what I want the end-result to look like (even quads allow me to have the textures repeated in a uniform manner)

